# Extending a class with more than one activity with interface in android

Tags: android, android-activity

Basically, I'm new with android and java and I know this question was asked for too many times, but I couldn't understand something.
I'm reading a guide that says I need to extend `AppCompatActivity`, so I could use the toolbar benefits from this class. Then I read another guide that says I need to extend another class, such as `ExpandableListActivity`. Both those classes weren't created by me. How can I create such an interface that can include both the classes, and implement it?

Comment: You can't. Java doesn't have multiple inheritance. If you want a ListView in your Activity, you can implement it yourself.

Comment: @TheWanderer I know, I said it. sorry if it wasn't clear. what can I do if I need something from both the classes?

Comment: Implement the function in your extended class yourself. You can use an AppCompatActivity and populate the ListView yourself.

Comment: ListActivity isn't something magical you need to use to have a ListView.  Its about 5-10 lines of code on top of Activity that tries to make it more convenient, and usually ends up not being worth using.  You can easily copy eveyrthing it does in about 3 minutes of coding.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to achieve isn't supported by java and you should make peace with it before embracing Android. The best thing you can do is implement the list functionality by yourself inside the same activity extending AppCompatActivity.